# I've got gradle sync error in Android Studio, "Could not find method calsspath() for arguments [com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0]"

Tags: maven, android-studio, github, gradle, synchronization

I was trying to make public library on Github. 
And I put some keywords on gradles.

-------------(build.gradle) for module----------------

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group='com.home'
version='1.0'
...
```

-------------(build.gradle) for project---------------

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        calsspath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
        ....
```

I think I typed all keywords correctly. But it keeps generating
sync-error message like below.

`"Could not find method calsspath() for arguments [com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."`

My graddle version is 4.4.

A little help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies for gradle plugins have to be defined in `buildscript` block at the beginning of your build file. In a simple single module project it would look like this:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

In case of a multi-module project, you need to put `buildscript` block in your root project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And I'm sorry that I didn't elaborate on the question. I did put "classpath" stuffs inside "buildscript { dependencies { ... } }" block. And yes, I am working on multi-module project.

Comment: Ah then it is just typo in `classpath`. You have `calsspath`

Comment: Oh my god. This is so embarrassing. I feel like to hide myself behind anything. Yes it was just a typo. Thank you @chalimartines.

Comment: Now I can see the error message clearly. It said "no method" not "no plugin 2.0". Thank you.

Comment: @Walter.JJ no worries :-) I'm glad I could help.